# Docker not detected by Tenable Nessus Expert in Mac OS

Tags: nessus

I have installed Tenable Nessus Expert (Trial version) in my Mac laptop. When I tried to enable Web Application Scanning (WAS) in the UI, it is not able to download WAS package because it cannot detect the Docker installed in the laptop.

Error: Determined one of the following cases: Docker (R) is not installed, Docker (R) is installed but is not started, Docker (R) is installed but the 'global.path_to_docker' preference needs to be set, or the version is not supported.

I tried to fix the global.path_to_docker using command however it did not help.

sudo /Library/Nessus/run/sbin/nessuscli fix --set global.path_to_docker=$HOME/.docker/bin

Can someone please help me what I am missing in the setup ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why @Weasley's answer got downvotes but it worked for me up to step 3. I did not need to restart anything though, after setting the correct path, got the message below and trying to pull the WAS docker image again worked.

```
Successfully set 'global.path_to_docker' to '/usr/local/bin/docker'.
The Nessus web server will be restarted.
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is step for fixed.

1. Verify Docker Installation

```
docker --version
docker info
```

2. Check Docker Status

```
docker ps
```

3. Set the Correct Docker Path

```
/usr/local/bin/docker.
sudo /Library/Nessus/run/sbin/nessuscli fix --set global.path_to_docker=/usr/local/bin/docker
```

4. Restart Nessus

```
sudo /Library/Nessus/run/sbin/nessuscli restart
```

5. Check Docker Compatibility
6. Review Nessus Logs usually located in the

```
/opt/nessus/var/nessus/logs/ directory.
```

7. Contact Tenable Support